# can you list shared folder sessions from command line?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, network-shares

if you right-click my computer and go to Computer Management -> System Tools -> SHared Folders -> Sessions you can see the list of network users currently connected to your shares.

can this list be displayed inside a cmd box?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`net session` will list that

Answer (score -2):

You can use

```
wmic share get caption,name,path
```

or

```
Net share
```